# Apigee proxy extracting common steps

Tags: apigee

Just trying to solve a scenario where I have a 5 steps repeating in most of the conditional flows. I am thinking of a away to extract this to a common place and use it in each conditional flow.
Note: Shared flow may not be possible as requirement is specific to proxy and preflow not possible since process is intermediate.

```
<Flow name="Flow-1">
   <Request>
      <Step>
        <Condition>Condition to execute those bunch of steps<Condition>
        <Name>This is where I need to do a bunch of steps (calling a separate flow or block like we do shared flow<Name>
      </Step>
   </Request>
</Flow>
```

Comment: If it's basic validations/read/set variables kind of steps and no KVM/cache/service callout involved, then JavaScript policy is an option.
I would still go with a shared flow if there's KVM/cache/service callout involved.